# How to change first folder after domain to subdomain with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to make a page builder.
Each user must automatically receive a sub domain.
The idea is that the first folder is put behind the / to a subdomain.

Example:
I create a folder: example.com/user/main/main
and that it is automatically changed to:
user.example.com/main/main

If there is no folder but only an index or other page, this should not happen.

How can i can i do that? I want to make it with php or htaccess.
Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please include the code you have already tried to your question and describe where you got stuck.

Comment: also it's not really clear what you want to achieve

Comment: @Jeff I have changed the question. Is this clear?